# Using git svn, I just rebased feature branch onto master and fast forwarded master. How do I check that my master's history is linear?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm using git svn and I have two local branches: master and feature.  My feature is done and now I want it to be part of the master branch.  I think I'm supposed to do this:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge feature --ff-only
```

Assuming that's right, I *should* be able to `git svn dcommit` master back to the svn repo.  But, is there a way to make sure my master is in the correct state before I attempt that?  Specifically, I want to make sure my master's history is linear.  How can I do that?

I tried running

```
git log --decorate --graph --oneline
```

But the output is massive and I'm not sure how to interpret it.  I think it may contain all the history of my svn repo.  All I want to see is the history of my local master to make sure it's linear.

Answer (score 2):

The output of

```
git log --merges
```

will be empty if your history is linear from your current `HEAD` back.

Comment: Hm, well it's not empty for me.  But all of them are from remote branches that I haven't committed to locally (as far as I recall) and all mention changes I haven't made.  What does that mean?

Comment: Study the output of `git log --decorate --graph --oneline`. Add it to your question if you don't understand anything.